# CSS breadcrumb: hide leftmost items

Tags: html, css, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to create a breadcrumb in CSS3. I want the last item to be fully visible. The leftmost items should leave the display area if needed.

The plunker so far:

http://plnkr.co/edit/VNtaYX?p=preview

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <ul>
        <li>...
```

I don't find a way to say: "ul, be as wide as you need. You may extend to the left, but don't go any further than the div.breadcrumb's right end".

Thanks for helping..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `white-space: nowrap;` do the trick for you on the last-of-type?

http://plnkr.co/edit/PLu13HZoPiZMBEjw6ehT?p=preview

Comment: Right indeed, I missed that :-) Thank you!